# Azure SQL Database Copy Database Stuck

Tags: database, sql, azure

I copied and pasted a database name from a Word document and pasted it into a T-SQL copy database command without realizing the formatting came with it (i.e. numbering).  Now I have something like this showing in SSMS but not in the portal, 2) MyTest-sqldb.  It shows as having a state description of Copying in sys.databases and it also still shows in sys.dm_database_copies after two weeks.  I can't delete the database in SSMS because it says that it doesn't exist.  Does anyone know if there is any way to interrupt this?  Thanks.